# Trying import Libgdx project with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying import Libgdx project with Gradle looks like this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBsvuT7MzpY 
The problem is when I execute import returns a exception and doesn't work.

Te exception is bellow

```
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.
```

How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Try updating to Gradle 1.12

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle  if possible?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler. How to updating Gradle ? I did download Gradle 1.12 and extract in /home/user/gradle-1.12